# Does a Facebook never expiring page token from an APP carry the same api call limitations as an APP ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does a Facebook never expiring page token from an APP carry the same api call limitations as an APP ID?

For instance I am using an APP ID to connect a facebook feed I've created and it does have a rate limit... as it makes calls to return posts from my facebook page. I can use a never expiring page token too that I've created from my APP too and that is the question, does that never expiring page token carry the same api rate limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to use the most specific Token, which would be a Page Token in that case. There are no specific limits, but in general there are limits "per Token". Using a separate Page Token for each Page is always better than using one App Token for all Pages.